# Need to make a row a specific color if it contains a specific text

Tags: conditional-formatting

```
17600 7724 T1 Clematis Complex 0725602889 20 Green Ave  R782.00 EFT -R782.00
17612 7527 T2 Duan De beer 0793008797      3 Dromedaris R480.00 EFT -R480.00
17613         Bukes                       15 sarida hof R300.00 EFT    R0.00
```

If Column C says T1, T2 or C1 it must make different colors for each "person"

if it does not have anything is Column C it must be a different color than the others.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What kind of software is used?

Comment: in excel i need to make a whole row a color if it says "T1", "T2", "C1"